# How to determine whether colour is within a range of shades

Tags: autohotkey, getpixel

I am not sure if this is possible as I have been looking for a few hours and cant find what I am looking for.

What i am doing is taking a color from a game panel which is semi translucent so the color which I am taking is always subtly changing. What is need is a way to check if it is +/- 10 or so shades of my desired color.

Something like 
If color1 is +/-10 of 0x?

I have tried using the image search to do similar but that didn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Robert's answer, you can compare the colors mathematically.

First start by separating the Red, Green, and Blue values.

```
ToRGB(color) {
    return { "r": (color >> 16) & 0xFF, "g": (color >> 8) & 0xFF, "b": color & 0xFF }
}
```

Then we need a function that compares the colors.  Each of thee variables holds a number representing the difference in the two color values.  For example if red is `255` in c1, and `200` in c2, `rdiff` will be `55`.  We use `Abs` so that we don't end up with `-55` when `c2` has a higher value.  Then we make sure the difference for each of these is less than our `vary`.

```
Compare(c1, c2, vary=20) {
    rdiff := Abs( c1.r - c2.r )
    gdiff := Abs( c1.g - c2.g )
    bdiff := Abs( c1.b - c2.b )

    return rdiff <= vary && gdiff <= vary && bdiff <= vary
}
```

Here's how it can be used.  We take some numbers, and then compare them to each other with the default vary of 20.

```
light_pink := ToRGB(0xFFAAFF)
darker_pink := ToRGB(0xFAACEF)
purple := ToRGB(0xAA00FF)


MsgBox % Compare(light_pink, dark_pink) ; True
MsgBox % Compare(light_pink, purple) ; False
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your read about the limitations of PixelGetColor: Known limitations:

*"A window that is partially transparent or that has one of its colors marked invisible (TransColor) typically yields colors for the window behind itself rather than its own.
PixelGetColor might not produce accurate results for certain applications. If this occurs, try specifying the word Alt or Slow in the last parameter."*

When using ImageSearch, you can specify the Delta of the colours. Example:

```
ImageSearch, FoundX, FoundY, %SearchRangeLeft%, %SearchRangeTop%, %SearchRangeRight%, %SearchRangeBottom%, *20 %ImageFile%
```

Here the ***20** indicates the variation in the range from 0 to 255 of my search colour. When searching for a pixel inside the image of 100,100,100 (RGB), it will match anything between 80,80,80 and 120,120,120. Hope this helps, but matching transparent colours is difficult and prone to errors. The smaller the image and search range the better (and faster)